# Janela Modal só abre e não fecha

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma janela modal dentro de uma div, ao passar o mouse em cima, eu faço com que a div mude de cor e abre uma janela modal com foto, o problema é que essa janela modal só abre, e simplesmente não fecha. Alguém pode me ajudar com isto, não sei mais a quem recorrer.

```
<script>
     function clique(img){
       var modalJ=document.getElementById("janelaModal");
       var modalI=document.getElementById("imgModal").src=["pg/CadastroUsuario.jpg"];
       var modalB=document.getElementById("btFechar");


       modalJ.style.display="block";
       modalI.src=img;
       modalB.onclick=function(){
        modalJ.style.display="none";
       }
     } 

    </script>

   <style type="text/css">
        .servico:hover {
         cursor: zoom-in;
         background:orange;
        }

     </style>
```

E aqui o código da div e da janela modal.

```
<article class="servico wow fadeInUp" onclick='clique("imgModal")';>        
<a href="#" class="fadeImg"><img src="imag/monitor.png" alt="Logo do sistema"></a>
    <div class="inner">         
    <a href="#"><center><h3>Tela Inicial</h3></center></a>
    <h4>Uma empresa segura e com seus dados bem guardados, protegidos e também gerando uma rede de informações mais rápida!.</h4>
    </div>  
         <div id="janelaModal">
         <span id="btFechar">X</span>
         <img id="imgModal">     
        </div>          
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que a modal está dentro do article que chama o onclick ao ser clicada, logo ao clicar no botão para fechar ao mesmo tempo está clicando no article que abre a modal.

O correto era a modal ser independente do article, mas no seu caso você pode evitar o *bubbling* adicionando no evento que fecha a modal o `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
modalB.onclick=function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   modalJ.style.display="none";
}
```

Com isso, ao clicar no botão que fecha a modal, não irá disparar o `onclick` do article (*bubbling*).

> ***Bubbling** (borbulhamento) de evento é um tipo de propagação de evento em que o evento dispara primeiro no elemento de destino mais
>   interno e, em seguida, dispara sucessivamente nos ancestrais do
>   elemento de destino na mesma hierarquia de aninhamento até alcançar o
>   elemento DOM ou objeto de documento mais externo.

Comment: Funcionou, mds muito muito muitoooo obrigado moço, salvou minha vida! Deus lhe abençoe.

Comment: Seja bem-vinda. Veja o que fazer quando uma resposta lhe atendeu neste link [tour]